# How do I put data into a dropdown box and be able search for it by typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am struggling to put data in a drop-down box. The data is NOT a pre-defined set of data, so it is not as simple as hard coding data into a drop-down box. The data is created, and once created I want it to populate in a drop-down box. At the moment the data is been displayed by check boxes. I also want to have a search function which will bring up intellisense. For example, when i type in "ALE" I want it to bring up data with the letters "ALE" in it, such as "Alex", "Alexander", "Alexis" etc. Please understand that i am very new to MVC.

In Short this what I am struggling to get out of my program. My program creates "Researchers" and once a "Researcher" is captured on the system, the "Researcher" can now make a research "Submission". So when a "Submission" is been captured, the "Researcher" should be able to search for his/her name (along with other names, if necessary) from the drop-down box. As there will be a lot of names, the "Researcher" should also have a search function along-side the drop-down.

Create Submission View:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Researchers", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        @{
                            int cnt = 0;
                            List<RMS.ViewModels.AssignedResearcherData> researchers = ViewBag.Researcher;

                            foreach (var researcher in researchers)
                            {
                                if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
                                {
                                    @:</tr><tr>
                                }
                                @:<td>
                                    <input type="checkbox"
                                        name="selectedResearchers"
                                        value="@researcher.ResearcherID"
                                        @(Html.Raw(researcher.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                                        @researcher.FullName
                                @:</td>
                            }
                            @:</tr>
                        }
             </div>
        </div>
```

Submission Controller:

```
private void PopulateAssignedResearcherData(Submission submission)
        {
            var allResearchers = db.Researcher;
            var submissionResearchers = new HashSet<int>(submission.Researcher.Select(i => i.ResearcherID));
            var viewModel = new List<AssignedResearcherData>();
            foreach (var researcher in allResearchers)
            {
                viewModel.Add(new AssignedResearcherData
                {
                    ResearcherID = researcher.ResearcherID,
                    FirstName = researcher.FirstName,
                    Surname = researcher.Surname,
                    Assigned = submissionResearchers.Contains(researcher.ResearcherID)
                });
            }
            ViewBag.Researcher = viewModel;
            // ViewBag.ResearcherSelect = new MultiSelectList(viewModel, "ResearcherID", "FullName");
        }
```

Comment: this may help:http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/01/searchable-dropdown-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 3rd party plugin suchs as Select2 to achieve dropdownlist searchable
https://select2.github.io/

All you need to do is instead of generating checkbox, generate Select with option then call select2:

```
//include library at top

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

// init select2
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myDDl').select2();
</script>



// generate select instead of checkbox   
<select id="myDDl" name="selectedResearchers" multiple="multiple">
 @foreach (var researcher in researchers)
 {
  <option value="@researcher.ResearcherID" 
       @(Html.Raw(researcher.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : ""))>
      @researcher.FullName
  </option>
}
</select>
```

Make sure to checkout select2 for more optionsyou can pass in
https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: Thanks for the help and putting me in the right direction. . However what the code does now is that it displays a 'select drop-down', what i was looking for was a 'multi-select drop-down'. i was trying to get a multi select but I couldn't get around it. Can you help in getting a multi-select option

Comment: @KivanIlangakoon I have modified the answer to include multiselect.
the change part is adding a multiple attribute in select:

<select id="myDDl" name="selectedResearchers" multiple="multiple">

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question I was not sure whether you were having trouble generating your dropdown box in the first place (but by your first sentence looks like you are).  Well if you are looking for help doing that then basically what you need to do is convert your `viewModel`list into a `MultipleSelectList` in C# and then generate the dropdown list in Razor -

C#

```
private void PopulateAssignedResearcherData(Submission submission)
    {
        var allResearchers = db.Researcher;
        var submissionResearchers = new HashSet<int>(submission.Researcher.Select(i => i.ResearcherID));
        var viewModel = new List<AssignedResearcherData>();
        foreach (var researcher in allResearchers)
        {
            viewModel.Add(new AssignedResearcherData
            {
                ResearcherID = researcher.ResearcherID,
                FirstName = researcher.FirstName,
                Surname = researcher.Surname,
                Fullname = researcher.FirstName + " " + researcher.Surname,
                Assigned = submissionResearchers.Contains(researcher.ResearcherID)
            });
        }
        ViewBag.Researcher = viewModel;
        ViewBag.ResearcherSelect = new MultiSelectList(viewModel, "ResearcherID", "FullName", viewModel.Where(rs => rs.Assigned);
    }
```

Razor

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Researchers", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    @{
                        int cnt = 0;
                        List<RMS.ViewModels.AssignedResearcherData> researchers = ViewBag.Researcher;

                        foreach (var researcher in researchers)
                        {
                            if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
                            {
                                @:</tr><tr>
                            }
                            @:<td>
                                @Html.TextBox("researcherSearch")
                                @Html.DropDownList("researcherList", ViewBag.ResearcherSelect)
                            @:</td>
                        }
                        @:</tr>
                    }
         </div>
    </div>
```

Once that is done it should be relatively simple to add in the search functionality using the suggestions in one of the other answers or jQuery UI's autocomplete (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

If you do go the jQuery UI route I would suggest maybe converting your `ViewBag.Researcher` variable to JSON to use as a datasource.