# how to pre-select from a multiple select box in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, select, drop-down-menu

I am new to mvc. 
we got this code to create a multiple select box from the link:

[How do I put data into a dropdown box and be able search for it by typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178486/how-do-i-put-data-into-a-dropdown-box-and-be-able-search-for-it-by-typing/32179367#32179367)

It works well, however when I implement the edit functionality, it doesn't display the "Researchers" selected from the create option.

below is the code used for the create and edit View:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Researchers", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                        @{
                            List<RMS.ViewModels.AssignedResearcherData> researchers = ViewBag.Researcher;
                            <select style="width: 185px; " multiple id="myDDl" class="chzn-select" name="selectedResearchers" data-placeholder="Please Select Researcher(s)">
                                @foreach (var researcher in researchers)
                                {
                                    <option value="@researcher.ResearcherID"
                                            @(Html.Raw(researcher.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : ""))>
                                        @researcher.FullName
                                    </option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        }
             </div>
        </div>
```

Below is the edit controller:

```
// GET: Submission/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Submission submission = db.Submission.Include(i => i.Researcher).Include(i => i.CESM).Include(i => i.Publication).Include(i => i.File).Include(i => i.AdditionalFile).Where(i => i.SubmissionID == id).Single();
            PopulateAssignedResearcherData(submission);
            if (submission == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.CESMID = new SelectList(db.CESM, "CESMID", "CESMCategory", submission.CESMID);
            ViewBag.PublicationID = new SelectList(db.Publication, "PublicationID", "Title", submission.PublicationID);
            return View(submission);
        }

        private void PopulateAssignedResearcherData(Submission submission)
        {
            var allResearchers = db.Researcher;
            var submissionResearchers = new HashSet<int>(submission.Researcher.Select(i => i.ResearcherID));
            var viewModel = new List<AssignedResearcherData>();
            foreach (var researcher in allResearchers)
            {
                viewModel.Add(new AssignedResearcherData
                {
                    ResearcherID = researcher.ResearcherID,
                    FirstName = researcher.FirstName,
                    Surname = researcher.Surname,
                    Assigned = submissionResearchers.Contains(researcher.ResearcherID)
                });
            }
            ViewBag.Researcher = viewModel;
        }

        // POST: Submission/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id, string[] selectedResearchers, HttpPostedFileBase upload, HttpPostedFileBase upload2)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var submissionToUpdate = db.Submission
               .Include(i => i.Researcher)
               .Include(i => i.CESM)
               .Include(i => i.Publication)
               .Where(i => i.SubmissionID == id)
               .Single();

            if (TryUpdateModel(submissionToUpdate, "",
               new string[] { "CESMID", "PublicationID", "Type", "Title", "Status", "Comment", "SubmissionDate", "CapturedOnRIMS", "NumberOfAuthors", "NumberOfWitsAuthors", "TotalPages", "PagesInPreamble", "PagesInText", "NumberOfChapters", "Location" }))
            {

                    UpdateSubmissionResearchers(selectedResearchers, submissionToUpdate);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
                {
                    //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
                }
            }
            PopulateAssignedResearcherData(submissionToUpdate);
            ViewBag.CESMID = new SelectList(db.CESM, "CESMID", "CESMCategory", submissionToUpdate.CESMID);
            ViewBag.PublicationID = new SelectList(db.Publication, "PublicationID", "Title", submissionToUpdate.PublicationID);
            return View(submissionToUpdate);
        }

        private void UpdateSubmissionResearchers(string[] selectedResearchers, Submission submissionToUpdate)
        {
            if (selectedResearchers == null)
            {
                submissionToUpdate.Researcher = new List<Researcher>();
                return;
            }

            var selectedResearchersHS = new HashSet<string>(selectedResearchers);
            var submissionResearchers = new HashSet<int>
                (submissionToUpdate.Researcher.Select(i => i.ResearcherID));
            foreach (var researcher in db.Researcher)
            {
                if (selectedResearchersHS.Contains(researcher.ResearcherID.ToString()))
                {
                    if (!submissionResearchers.Contains(researcher.ResearcherID))
                    {
                        submissionToUpdate.Researcher.Add(researcher);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (submissionResearchers.Contains(researcher.ResearcherID))
                    {
                        submissionToUpdate.Researcher.Remove(researcher);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Submission Model:

```
public class Submission
    {
        public int SubmissionID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Publication")]
        public int? PublicationID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="CESM Category")]
        public int CESMID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Submission Date")]
        public DateTime SubmissionDate { get; set; }
        public bool CapturedOnRIMS { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number Of Authors")]
        public int NumberOfAuthors { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number Of Wits Authors")]
        public int NumberOfWitsAuthors { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Total Pages")]
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Pages In Preamble")]
        public int PagesInPreamble { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Pages In Text")]
        public int PagesInText { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number Of Chapters")]
        public int NumberOfChapters { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Researcher> Researcher { get; set; }
        public virtual Publication Publication { get; set; }
        public virtual CESM CESM { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Document")]
        public virtual ICollection<File> File { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Additional Document")]
        public virtual ICollection<AdditionalFile> AdditionalFile { get; set; }
    }
```

Researcher Model:

```
public class Researcher
    {
        public int ResearcherID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="School")]
        public int SchoolID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }       
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Registration Date")]
        public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Qualification Type")]
        public string QualificationType { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Job Name")]
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        public string Availability { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Researcher Full Name")]
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return Surname + ", " + FirstName;
            }
        }
        public virtual ICollection<Submission> Submission { get; set; }
        public virtual School School { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the model for `Submission` (in particular the property your wanting to bind to).

Comment: OK I have updated my question with the "Submission" and "Researcher" Model.

Comment: You did not need to include all the properties :) It does not appear you have any property named `selectedResearchers` so there is nothing to bind to. Unfortunately the answer in the link is dreadful code. You have posted far too much irrelevant code here, but is the idea that your displaying a list box with all researchers and you want to show any previously selected researcher as being selected in the listbox?

Comment: my apologies. I do realize that I have uploaded far too much irrelevant code. Fortunately I manage to fix my problem. The problem was in the view. Change

Comment: I doubt you have really fixed it (you probably don't realize all the other issues you will have with this). What you should have is a view model with properties `int[] SelectedResearchers` and `SelectList ResearchList` and in the view `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedResearchers, Model.ResearchList)`

Answer (score 1):

It was a silly mistake I had made in the edit view.
I replaced "checked" with "selected"

below is the new edit view:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Researchers", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                        @{
                            List<RMS.ViewModels.AssignedResearcherData> researchers = ViewBag.Researcher;
                            <select multiple id="myDDl" class="chzn-select" name="selectedResearchers" >
                                @*<option selected=""></option>*@
                                @foreach (var researcher in researchers)
                                {
                                    <option value="@researcher.ResearcherID"
                                            @(Html.Raw(researcher.Assigned ? "selected=\"selected\"" : ""))>
                                        @researcher.FullName
                                    </option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        }
                </div>
            </div>
```